# is it possible to get the length of an axis directly in a biom.Table object?

Tags: python, biom

Is it possible to directly lookup the length of an axis in a [`biom.Table`](http://biom-format.org/documentation/generated/biom.table.Table.html) object, or do you need to do something like the following, where `t` is a `Table` object:

```
if axis == 'sample':
    length = t.shape[0]
elif axis == 'observation':
    length = t.shape[1]
else:
   raise UnknownAxisError(axis)
```

It seems like a better way to do this would be with a method like `t.length(axis)`. Does functionality like that exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best method right now would be:

```
>>> from biom import example_table
>>> axis = 'sample'
>>> print example_table.ids(axis).size
3
```

`__len__` currently isn't overloaded because it isn't clear what axis should be returned. It may make sense to have a `length` method though, and if you think it would be clearer to have, the best next step would be to create an issue on the github [project](https://github.com/biocore/biom-format/issues).

Comment: Thanks, that is definitely cleaner than what I was suggesting. I think a ``length`` method would be useful - I created [an issue here](https://github.com/biocore/biom-format/issues/548).